# Windows 8 App, change colour of BackButtonStyle

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a Windows store app which requests the Dark theme by default. This is great apart from one of the pages needs to be white. I placed everything inside a grid and changed the background to white.. everything is working fine, apart from my navigation button is styled as:

```
<Button Foreground="Black" x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" />
```

{StaticResource BackButtonStyle} returns a white button (due to my Apps Dark theme), so the back button is invisible against the white background.

How can I change the colour of this back button to black? i.e so it will show a black arrow inside a black circle.

I've tried creating my own style in StandardStyles.xaml without any joy:

```
<Style x:Key="PortraitBackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="26,0,26,36"/>
</Style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I find it stunning how the XAML team haven't just template-bound the Button.Foreground to the glyphs that make up the visuals on this buttons so we can just set the Foreground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this style in `StandardStyles.xaml` file and use it in your back button

```
<Color x:Key="Color1">#ffffff</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color2">#000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color3">#666666</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBackButtonNormalBrush" Color="{StaticResource Color2}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBackButtonBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Color1}"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBackButtonHoverBrush" Color="{StaticResource Color3}"/>

<Style x:Key="MyBackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="36,0,36,36"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MyBackButtonHoverBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MyBackButtonNormalBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MyBackButtonNormalBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="-1,-16,0,0">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" Foreground="{StaticResource MyBackButtonBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{StaticResource BackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{StaticResource MyBackButtonNormalBrush}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0A6;" Foreground="{StaticResource MyBackButtonBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                    <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: instead of 
<Color x:Key="Color1">#ffffff</Color> //white background
it is better to be 
<Color x:Key="Color1">#00FFFFFF</Color> 
with transparent Background

Comment: @kartal Use according to your need :)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore without knowing XAML at all, this can't be smart Compaired to clean css

Comment: @SimonPertersen I have very less knowledge of css

Answer (score 1):

if Your Background is white 
You Can write at Back Button Property the Following Code :

```
   <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
  Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                            RequestedTheme="Light"
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                            AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious solution – to re-style controls. But you don't want to type style name every time you need to add control to UI. Also you usually use input controls on a dark background so you don’t even need two different styles. In this case a different approach can be used.

#### The solution:

First, open:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design\themeresources.xaml

and search for "Dark" ResourceDictionary declaration. Copy all SolidColorBrush object definitions associated with buttonsa and finally paste all the brushes into your resource dictionary, and you can use it.

**Source:**: [Mixing themes in XAML Metro apps](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/06/21/winrt-xaml-themes/)

Answer (score 0):

To apply Light theme/Dark theme(as per your requirement), just copy the following code into StandardStyles.xaml and do change the respective resoluce

1)For Light Theme

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBackgroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBorderThemeBrushLight" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrushLight" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#66000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#FF000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#3D000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#FF000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrushLight" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

For Dark Theme

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBackgroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorButtonFaceColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBorderThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorButtonFaceColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorGrayTextColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorButtonTextColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorHighlightTextColor}" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource SystemColorButtonFaceColor}" />
```

and accordingly change

```
AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush to AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrushLight/AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrushDark
```

refer these links for customising the App Bar
[Here](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/06/21/winrt-xaml-themes/) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031365/how-do-i-mix-light-and-dark-themes-in-a-c-xaml-windows-store-metro-ui-app)

It'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

Within the code you could change the style via code after the controls have been initialized.

Cheers
Mark