# How do I mix Light and Dark themes in a C#/XAML Windows Store (Metro UI) App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

According to MSDN, the standard way of setting your app theme is to set `RequestedTheme="Dark"` or `RequestedTheme="Light"` on the toplevel `Application` instance.

This works great for simple apps but many times I find myself wanting to change the theme of an individual page or even an individual control (e.g. a light-themed text edit page vs a dark-themed image viewer in the same app).

XAML controls have 10s or 100s of visual states and color definitions and setting each one of them by hand is tedious and difficult to get 100% right!

Is there an easy way to set a dark or light theme on an individual control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a XAML windows store app, the default look-and-feel of controls is defined in `Common/StandardStyles.xaml`. If you've ever looked at that file, you'll notice a ton of references like `{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}`. Looks promising...

Unfortunately, these "theme brushes" aren't defined anywhere in your app, and there's no easy way to set a light or dark override for individual controls. However, there is an answer.

Fortunately, [there's an excellent blog post by Joe White](http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes) on the default theme colors, which [I've turned into a resource dictionary that you can find here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pkxwgmgekh2v2q/ThemeColors.xml). Dropbox only does xml previews so you'll have to rename the file.

Copying these resources to your app won't help by itself though. To make use of them, you need to surgically override the default control styles to use them!

One way to do this is to create a new resource dictionary, e.g. at `Common/CustomStyles.xaml`, and merge that into the app's resources like so:

```
<Application
    x:Class="My.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                <!-- 
                    Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                    Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
                 -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/ThemeColors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/CustomStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Notice that our default theme is `Light`. If we'd like to make a `Dark`-themed `TextBlock`, let's copy the visual style from `StandardStyles.xaml` and add it to our `CustomStyles.xaml` and make a few changes.

```
<Style x:Key="BasicRichTextStyleDark" TargetType="RichTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrushDark}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.StylisticSet20" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.CaseSensitiveForms" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

**Notice that we have appended `Dark` to the style name and the theme brush definitions!** You can do this via find and replace `"ThemeBrush}"` => `"ThemeBrushDark}"` in your CustomStyles.xaml file.

Now you can create a dark-themed text block like so:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BasicRichTextStyleDark}"/>
```

Of course, you can use this technique for any other type of control as well. A little tedious, but the results are correct and it's not nearly as bad as trying to define every color manually!

**There's no magic here.** We're just defining some colors and overriding a default style with one that we copy-pasted and modified to use our colors.

Comment: Your XAML file is fantastic.  Saved so much time as I was just about to start on one myself. Everyone should have a copy of this. I don't think people fully understand themes as I've come across many Apps that seem to break when changing from the theme they were developed in. If you are going to start changing default controls then much better to force the app into a theme and use this xaml to create the correct styled controls when you go against the selected theme.

Comment: Thanks Oli, glad it was useful for someone else as well!

Comment: the XAML file is a 404 now. Can you upload it to more persistent storage? Perhaps a github gist? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A solution that surprisingly does not seem to be mentioned is just to use **RequestedTheme="Dark"** or **RequestedTheme="Light"** on the individual control elements.

I do that for an app where I needed to set some appbarbuttons to the dark setting (which is white foreground) - because the Foreground property did not set both the circle and the glyph itself to white:

```
<AppBarButton Label="Reload all articles" RequestedTheme="Dark" >
```

This way, I just force the control to use the theme I decide.

Answer (score 1):

In folder Common you have a StandardStyles.xaml file.

Here you can find all standard styles default for Metro Applications.
You need to uncomment styles what you want to use and add to control as StaticResource.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same problem while Designing my App "Contact Book", because i also wanted the change between Dark & Light themes. For your que : "**How do I mix Light and Dark themes in a C#/XAML Windows Store (Metro UI) App?**", I have a **superb solution.**

- I have made two pages with same code & same content. I added both those pages one above another and then I've made a dynamic change between those two kind of themes Light & Dark. I gave an option to user whether they want Dark layout or Light layout & as per user's choice I've applied the theme.  I succeeded in this case.

**Second solution:**

- If you want dynamic look and feel for your application, then you have
  to made your own static layout type and then you can bind your that
  static resource to the page on which you want to apply that kind of
  style.

pardon if you don't find your answer here, but i thought it might help you to **dynamically change between "Dark" & "Light" themes** setting in your win 8 metro app.